Self join to compare rows of table?
We are using SQL Server 2017 for our document management application. In our application one document can have many versions. Access can be given to users at revision level. We store user access information in DOCUMENT_ACL table.



DocId
RevisionId
UserId




11
101
1001


11
101
1002


11
101
1003


11
102
1003


11
102
1004


11
103
1004


11
103
1005




UserId 1001 , 1002 & 1003 has access to RevisionId 101.
UserId 1003 & 1004 has access to RevisionId 102.
UserId 1004 & 1005 has access to RevisionId 103.

We have complex requirement to show only latest revision to user have access to.
We want to write a stored procedure to return resultset as below.
e.g.



RevisionId
UserIds




101
1001,1002


102
1003


103
1004,1005



For RevisionId 103 (Version 3 - Latest) it should return both UserId 1004 & 1005.
For RevisionId 102 (Version 2) it should return only UserId 1003 (as 1004 user is already return for version 103).
For RevisionId 101 (Version 1) it should return only UserId 1001 & 1002 (as 1003 user is already return for version 102).
We looked at self join to achieve above but it look too complex.
Please suggest how we can implement above logic in a stored procedure.

Do these answer your question? Get top 1 row of each group & Comma separated results in SQL

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

"but it look too complex"   Why did it look complext?  What exactly did you try?

From a business perspective, it doesn't make much sense to have more than one active/effective version of a document in document control. Typically, the latest version is "active" and all previous versions are "obsolete". What is the requirement for user-based version access?

Sounds like a simple group by?
with data as (
    select docid, rev
    , users
    from (
        values  (11, 101, 1001)
        ,   (11, 101, 1002)
        ,   (11, 101, 1003)
        ,   (11, 102, 1003)
        ,   (11, 102, 1004)
        ,   (11, 103, 1004)
        ,   (11, 103, 1005)
        ) x(docid,rev, users)
)
select docid, maxrev, string_agg(users,',') as users
from (
    select  docid, max(rev) as maxrev, users
    from    data
    group by docid, users
    ) x
group by docid, maxrev

Outputs:



docid
maxrev
users




11
101
1001,1002


11
102
1003


11
103
1004,1005




Select all revisions, and exclude users that have higher revision available:
SELECT 
  da1.RevisionId, 
  STRING_AGG(da1.UserId,',')  UserIds
FROM DOCUMENT_ACL da1
WHERE da1.UserId NOT IN (SELECT da2.UserId
                         FROM DOCUMENT_ACL da2
                         WHERE da2.RevisionId > da1.RevisionId)
GROUP BY da1.RevisionId

see: DBFIDDLE
this assumes data is like this:
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT_ACL (
  DocID INT,
  RevisionId INT,
  UserId INT);

INSERT INTO DOCUMENT_ACL VALUES
  (11,101,1001),
  (11,101,1002),
  (11,101,1003),
  (11,102,1003),
  (11,102,1004),
  (11,103,1004),
  (11,103,1005);


To get expected result, we can write the SQL query using ROW_NUMBER() function to identify latest RevisionID, grouped by UserID.
Here is the query:
DECLARE @vTbl AS TABLE
(
    DocId INT NULL
    , RevisionId INT NULL
    , UserID INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @vTbl (DocId, RevisionId, UserID)
SELECT 11 AS DocID, 101 AS RevisionId, 1001 AS UserID
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 101, 1002
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 101, 1003
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 102, 1003
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 102, 1004
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 103, 1004
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 103, 1005;

SELECT a.DocId, a.RevisionId, a.UserID 
FROM @vTbl AS a

SELECT DISTINCT
    a.DocId
    , a.RevisionId
    , (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(t.UserId, ',') 
        FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY DocId, RevisionId DESC) AS RNo, * FROM @vTbl 
        ) AS t
        WHERE t.RNo = 1
        AND t.DocId = a.DocId 
        AND t.RevisionId= a.RevisionId
      ) AS UserIdCsv2
FROM @vTbl AS a;

GO

Result:

